# how to achieve rollback in Apache camel in activemq using springframe work

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

i am using apache camel with activemq. I have configured my consumers which runs an exe file. this exe file will inturn run an application.

I want the message to be in the queue until this process happens. So, if my exe crashes/orexe is renamed etc i want the message to be in queue. Similarly say if the exe works fine and it call the application and something happens to the application even then i need the messages to be retained in the queue. If these two process happens successfully then my message can get dequeued.

i have written this logic using simple java code using session and redelivery policy. but i want to rewrite using spring framework(camel is integrated using this) and i am not sure on how to go about this. PS i am not looking for errors like message not being delivered to exe but issue like how to retain the message in the eventualities explained above

the activemqcamel.xml configuration is as below. the reason why i am posting this is config doesnt have the connection factory etc so there should be some way the apache camel is creating a session.

```
<camelContext id="activeContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <routeBuilder ref="activeMQRouter" />
  </camelContext>

  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
<property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616?          jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1" />
</bean>

  <bean id="activeMQRouter"      class="main.java.com.aranin.activemq.ActiveMQRouterBuilder"/>

  <bean id="activemqProcessor" class="main.java.com.aranin.activemq.ActiveMQProcessor"/>
```

** the old code on how i was achieving the roll back*********************

```
package PackageName;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy;
 public class FirstConsumer extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException{
try {
//creating connectionfactory object for way
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61617?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1");
//creating object for RedeliveryPolicy clas
RedeliveryPolicy policy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(1000L);
policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(RedeliveryPolicy.NO_MAXIMUM_REDELIVERIES);
connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(policy);
connectionFactory.setUseRetroactiveConsumer(true);
//establishing the connection b/w this Application and Activemq
Connection connection=connectionFactory.createConnection();
//connection.setClientID("Testing");
final Session session=connection.createSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue=session.createQueue("ThermalMap");
javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(queue);
//Creating FunctionNames class object for calling integration method.
final FunctionNames functionNamesObject=new FunctionNames();
//Listening queues from Activemq
MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        //getting message, and converting message object to Textmessage object
        TextMessage msg1=(TextMessage)msg;
        try {
            functionNamesObject.Integration(
                                            ".txt",
                                            getServletContext().getRealPath("/Copy"),
                                            getServletContext().getRealPath("/Rod1"),
                                            "ThMapInfratab1-2.exe",
                                            "TMapInput.txt"
            );
            //Triggering MMA Application
            //functionNamesObject.executeHttp("http://localhost:8080/SlicerApp/index.jsp");
            session.commit();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                session.rollback();
            } catch (JMSException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            try {
                session.rollback();
            } catch (JMSException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            try {
                session.rollback();
            } catch (JMSException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
};
consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
connection.start();    
//session.rollback();
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about transactions at: http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html

Comment: i have read this doc. I think that this is more of handling transactional error. from( activeMqURI).to("bean:activemqProcessor?method=processMessage"); this transaction is happening fine but in the processmessage i am calling an exe. If this exe doesnt execute for some reason then i want my message to be rolled back. please correct me if i am wrong in my understanding

Comment: @ClausIbsen In our old code we used `session `. This session won't be end until application complete. We use `session.commit()` at end, so once application complete its exection message will pass from pending list to dequeue list. If there is any error happens while running application, we do `session.rollback()`, so that the message still be there in pending list for consumer to consume and process again.

Comment: @ClausIbsen In our new code(camel integration with activemq), we don't use session, since camel itself take care of that. we don't know how to rollback message when error happens while execution of .exe/application.